# Spring @RestController with @RequestBody @Valid by default

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Usually we write

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test2(@RequestBody @Valid TestClass req) {
        return "test2";
    }
}
```

But since it is a REST controller is it possible to configure Spring to use  @RequestBody @Valid by default, so these annotations could be omitted?

Comment: It will work without @RequestBody  in case of model entities.

Comment: Do you mean if TestClass will have @Entity annotation?

Comment: No you cannot as Spring has no way of knowing which of the arguments (if there would be multiple) to use for the `RequestBody`. You could create your own custom annotation with your own extensions which does this but personally I wouldn't bother as this would be confusing to others reading your code.